# Проблема с проектирование БД mysql для сайта сеиалов

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, проектирование

Есть сущности. Сущности имеют информацию, которая разбивается по группам.

Например: сущность 1  имеет группы с номерами 1 и 2, в которых также хранятся сущности.

Например: в группе 1 хранится сущность А, а в группе 2 хранится сущность Б. Эти сущности одного типа.

У групп и сущностей, находящихся в группах есть идентичные атрибуты, в которых хранятся разные значения.

Проблема в том, что у сущностей первого порядка, если хранить атрибуты в отдельной таблице и использовать в качестве внешних ключей суррогатные ключи таблиц сущностей первого порядка, таблицы групп, и таблицы сущностей находящиеся в группе, то появляются ячейки со значением `null`.

Другое значение вставить нельзя, так-как идет ограничение уникальности. Проще на конкретном примере -> [db_series](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ir2CEeKL_L9NNgQxUm0JnLCPwKft1sLbXm4Dsr66DZg/edit?usp=sharing). Ячейки с `null` в таблицах с номерами 5 - 8.

Бд проектируется для сайта сериалов. Сущности первого порядка - сериалы, группы - сезоны сериалов. Сущности хранящиеся в группа - это разумеется серии сезонов.
Идентичные атрибуты - `title`, `keywords`, `description`, комментарии, скриншоты, постеры.

Есть ли для моего случая шаблон проектирования? Как избавиться от ячеек с `null`?

Может разбить `title`и вставить непосредственно в таблицы сериалов, сезонов, комментариев и тп?

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу проблемы хранить записи таблицы один ко многим. Просто не делайте столбец уникальным, оставьте его индексом и все.

Ошибка `NULL` у вас возникает, скорее всего, не из-за неправильности архитектуры базы данных, а из-за ошибок в коде записи в базу.

З.Ы. никакой специальной архитектуры тут не требуется, все достаточно прозрачно на мой взгляд.

Comment: null это не ошибка, а вынужденная мера из за ограничения уникальности.

Answer (score 1):

У сущностей "Сериалы", "Сезоны", "Серии" очень много общих свойств. Вы пишите год к сериалу, но информация о годах выхода сезонов и серий то же может быть интересна. Актерский состав у вас только к сериалу, но в дальнейшем может быть интересен и состав для конкретных серий (кстати рекомендую сделать справочник актеров и связующую таблицу в которой еще может быть отражена исполняемая роль и режиссеры могут быть в этой же таблице). На imdb.com и много где еще рейтинг есть не только у сериала целиком но и у серий.

Итого наши сущности на столько похожи, что мы можем сделать вывод, что все они - это одна и та же сущность. Предлагаю создать для сериалов, сезонов и серий одну общую таблицу. Организуем таблицу в виде дерева. У сущности может быть заполнено поле "родитель" - у сезона это сериал, у серии сезон. У сериала поле "родитель" NULL.

```
create table db_series(
  id_series int not null auto_increment,
  id_parent int,          -- ID родителя
  type tinyint not null,  -- Тип: 1-сериал, 2-сезон, 3-серия 
  name varchar(200),      -- Название
  orig_name varchar(200), -- Оригинальное название
  prod_date date,         -- Дата выхода
  primary key(id_series),
  foreign key (id_parent)
   references db_series(id_series)
);
```

Все остальные таблицы для ссылки содержат единственный ID и ссылаются на нужный уровень иерархии. Нужно ли поле "Тип" для быстрого определения, что это такое, решайте сами.

Так как уровень иерархии не большой, то возможностей MySQL в принципе хватит, что бы с ним спокойно работать. Хотя лучше конечно брать СУБД поддерживающую иерархические запросы (например postgresql).

Comment: Спасибо за решение. Я после публикации вопроса сдеал так: сериалы, сезоны и серии разделил на отдельные таблицы и создал таблицу их связей, в которой есть 4 поля, первое id автоинкремент, а следующие  3 внешние ключи из таблиц - сериалы, сезоны и серии. Получается так: строка сериала выглядит так - id сериала, null, null; строка сезона - null, id сезона, null; строка серии - null, null, id серии. Ваше решение мне нравится больше, как вы считаете?

Comment: @АлександрРезов т.е. общий ID у вас все таки появился, это правильно. тянуть по куче подчиненных таблиц несколько полей - явно напрашивается связующая сущность. "Мое" решение мне конечно больше нравится, минус лишняя таблица в запросах, да еще с какими нибудь дикими left join с тремя таблицами, если запрос заходит с другой стороны (найти все где снимался актер, например). А "мое" в кавычках, потому, что такая структура прослеживается в том же imdb.com, у них общие id у сериалов и серий. сезоны правда где то отдельно